# Database not connecting with server on different host CakePHP version 2.0.0-dev

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, phpmyadmin, cakephp-2.0

I am facing problem while connecting cake php version-2.0.0-dev application on server. When I connect  with localhost database, it works fine on server, but if I try to connect it with the database of the different server which is being hosted by another host, it gives following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getAttribute() on a non-object in
/home/dev.ukssmain/public_html/stock_system_ukrs/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo/dbo_mysql.php
on line 259**
```

My configuration in database.php file is like

```
public $default = array(
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'connect' => 'mysql_connect',
'host' => 'test.com',
'port' => '3306',
'login' => 'test',
'password' => 'test',
'database' => 'test',
'prefix' => ''
);
```

Can anybody help me to get through this.

Comment: If you're not confident enough to debug the code yourself - why do you choose development version, which is unstable by definition?

Comment: Are you sure the other host allows outside connections to mysql? Allot of the time hosts will only allow connections form within their network, or require you to put any external client IP addresses on a whitelist. Can you connect to the DB from that server using the commandline mysql client?

Comment: You should enable MySQL remote on the other server, because servers usually allow connections from their local network. the procedure is different from server to server, but if you have CPanel , you can login to CPanel and add your IP to the Remote MySQL section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you should update to 2.0.6 (latest stable 2.0.x), or 2.2.2 which is the latest stable. You can find them [here](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/tags).

2.0.0-dev is unstable and outdated, you should use a stable version instead. I don't know why you'd want to run a production site with a -dev version, you're asking for problems.

Database configuration info can be found [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/configuration.html#database-configuration).